# Не передает ID на страницу редактирования

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Пишу на asp.net mvc , сделал таблицу на Kendo grid, реализовал удаление данных, а при попытке реализовать удаление произошла проблема, не передается ID строки

Вот мой скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function () {
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/Book/GetJsonBook",
            dataType: "json"
        },

        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
            }
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                Name: { validation: { required: true } },
                Author: { validation: { required: true } },
                YearOfPublishing: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    columns: [
        { field: "Name", title: "Name", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
        { field: "Author", title: "Author", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
        { field: "YearOfPublishing", title: "Year of publishing", width: "120px" },
        { command: { text: "Delete", click: deleteBook }, width: "50px" },
        { command: { text: "Edit", click: editBook }, width: "50px" },
        //{ command: { text: "Details", click: detailsBook }, title: " ", width: "100px" }],
    ],
}).data("kendoGrid");

});

function deleteBook(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
var dataItem = this.dataItem(row);
DeleteBook(dataItem.Id);
grid.removeRow(row);
}

function DeleteBook(ID) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Book/DeleteBook/" + ID,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
    },
});
};

function editBook(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");
var dataItem = this.dataItem(row);
EditBook(dataItem.Id);
}

function EditBook(ID) {
window.location.replace("EditBook");
};
```

Для удаления ID срабатывает ,а для редактирования нет

```
function EditBook(ID) {
window.location.replace("EditBook");
};
```

здесь я пытаюсь перейти на страницу редактирования

пробовал сделать так

```
function EditBook(ID) {
window.location.replace("EditBook") + ID;
};
```

но результат тот же

вот сама ошибка

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditBook(Int32)' in 'Library.WEB.Controllers.BookController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters]
```

Если нужно больше информации, пишите -я дополню

Comment: window.location.replace("EditBook"+ID)

Comment: так он передается ,но возникла другая проблема , айдишник записывается в адрес `/Book/EditBook37("37" - ID)`, я просто думал что смогу перейти на страницу и туда закинуть ID , как я сделал это здесь `url: "/Book/DeleteBook/" + ID`,

Comment: @Simom, не слишком понятно с `/Book/EditBook37("37" - ID)`
В каком случае возникает такая потребность

Comment: это не потребность , это результат этой строки `window.location.replace("EditBook"+ID)`

Comment: в таком случае посмотрите что приходит в `ID`
в любом случае Вам скорее всего понадобится делать урл по типу `/Book/EditBook/37` нежели `/Book/EditBook37`

Answer (score 0):

```
function EditBrochure(ID) {
    window.location.replace("/Brochure/EditBrochure/" + ID);
};
```